# В Бутово или Бутове

Tags: лингвистика

Как правильно произносить: в Бутово или Бутове

Answer (score 2):

Я предпочитаю только несклоняемый вариант, и вот почему.В Грамматике-80 говорится, что в профессиональной речи  такие названия не склоняются (у речки Каменка, рядом с Усово), так как там требуется абсолютная точность передачи топонима. В нашей обычной речи также возникают ситуации,когда такая точность необходима, и это в первую очередь касается названий на ОВО/ЕВО, ИНО/ЫНО. Можно себе представить, то есть два населенных пункта: Бутово и Бутов.  Мне бы   хотелось  различать их падежные формы тоже, однако форма "в Бутове" такой возможности нам не предоставляет. Думаю,что именно поэтому несклоняемый вариант вытесняет склоняемый - такой своеобразный "народный протест" против "строгой литературной нормы", которая не кажется правильной.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ.
Я тоже говорю о современной речи. Просто профессиональный принцип можно применить и для обычных названий, если мы хотим различать топонимы мужского и среднего рода. А общее правило я сформулировала бы так:
Топонимы на О НЕ СКЛОНЯЮТСЯ при наличии родового наименования: Церковь входит в состав усадьбы Абрамцево.  Занятие села Бородино имело для французов важное значение.   При отсутствии родового возможны ОБА ВАРИАНТА: Сражение под Бородино началось 6 сентября 1812 года. Недаром помнит вся Россия про день Бородина! Как вы отнеслись бы к такой формулировке?

Comment: Указанная причина повлияла на тенденцию к неизменяемости в 40- годы, Сталин лично приказал не склонять топонимы, чтобы не было ошибок в донесениях. Но это называется профессиональной речью, а мы говорим о современной норме, о ней спрашивает автор вопроса. Я и говорю, что оба варианты верны, но предпочтителен склоняемый, если следовать классической норме, как у Лермонтова: "В день Бородина"

Comment: Я согласен с Софией. Я не специалист в лингвистике, но по мне так:
- если мы говорим "в Бутове", то имеется в виду населённый пункт Бутов,
-если говорим "в Бутово", то подразумеваем Бутово.

Answer (score 1):

И так, и так, но более грамотным считается склоняемость, например, в Свиблове, Медведкове,"в день Бородина". Приведу цитату из Грамоты : "Русская грамматика" 1980 г. указывала: "Географические названия на -ово, -ево и -ино, -ыно: Иваново, Бирюлево, Кунцево, Сараево, Болдино, Бородино, Голицыно и под. в современной разговорной, профессиональной, газетной речи обнаруживают тенденцию к неизменяемости. Несмотря на это, в письменной речи, в соответствии с действующими грамматическими правилами, географические названия на -ов(о), -ёв(о), -ев(о), -ин(о), -ын(о) склоняются: В небе над Тушином (газ.); Речь идет об аэропорте в Шереметьеве (газ.). Несклоняемость географических наименований нормальна в следующих случаях: 1) Если такое наименование является приложением к одному из следующих обобщающих слов: село, деревня, поселок, станция, становище, реже - город: в селе Васильково, в поселке Пушкино, в деревне Белкино, на станции Гоголево. 2) Если населенный пункт назван собственным именем известного лица: около Репино (назв. поселка под Ленинградом), недалеко от Лермонтово (назв. небольшого города около Пензы)".

Сейчас  несклоняемые варианты стали настолько широко распространенными, что изначально единственно правильный склоняемый вариант сегодня многими воспринимается как ошибочный. Если когда-то Анна Ахматова возмущалась, когда при ней говорили мы живем в Кратово вместо мы живем в Кратове, то в наши дни употребление в Кратове, в Строгине, в Пулкове многими совершенно напрасно воспринимается как порча языка. Между тем такое произношение и написание соответствует строгой литературной норме.

Comment: Мне тоже тяжело говорить "в Строгине", "в Марьине", "в Бирюлеве", "в Братееве"... 

А "в Кратове" можно трактовать двояко: Кратове и Кратово. Сразу не поймешь, если ее знаешь, о чем речь.

Кстати, со множественным числом не возникает проблем. Например, никто не скажет "живу в Печатники" или "живу в Кузьминки".